# Saving html content to database

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

Still struggling very much with how to accomplish saving div+contents/layout to a database and then retrieveing that data to post back.

Can any one possibly help? I have it in my previous questions including my website link to show what im trying to achieve.

Thanks to any one who can help?

Comment: Are you trying to save the HTML itself, or are you trying to format data from the database in a certain way (so you are saving the whole thing)?

Comment: if the contents of the div is visible by 'view source', (no ajax), and you can modify the code, you may just get the page into php with file_get_contents and filter out the div with regexp or strpos.. Anyhow, by explaining clearer you'll get better help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are currently updating the page using jQuery/javascript once a user types something.

```
 $('#test1').append('<div id="test">' + x + '</div>');
```

Instead, post the user text to the server using `$.post()` or `$.ajax()`, write an aspx page on the server that handles those requests, and add the content (unformatted preferably, no html tags) to the DB.

If a client requests the updated page, send the page frame as is but use i.e. a repeater or another looping construct to add in the content from the DB.

Comment: yaaayy finally! some one who understands what im trying to do lol can I pick your brain!

Comment: @Garrith - there are some pretty good examples on the jQuery web site, see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/